# How to place a DIV regarding to lower left hand-side corner?

Tags: html, css, styles

I would like to add `li`s in a `DIV`. This `DIV` as a frame for the fieldset has no `width` and no `height`. The size should automatically be sized by using padding. The problem is that the `DIV` is an element of a class of another `DIV`:

```
<div class="flag">
    <div id="drop_up">
        <fieldset>
            <ul>
                <li>
                some content
                </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

Okay, the `li`'s will be inserted automatically through a loop.

Now the problem is, that the DIV is a drop-up frame. The size of that grows upwards and not downwands as usual. So I can not position this by using left, bottom etc. because the height will be different depending from the numbers of `li`'s.

My question is if there is a way to position an element by lower left hand-side corner? Usually the positioning takes effect on the upper right hand-side corner what would be no problem when the `DIV` is growing downwards.

If there is someone who can help me out I really would appreciate.

Thanks alot.

Comment: +1 for a good question.  I'm stumped, outside of using flexbox, I can't think of a way I'd do it.

Comment: Do you have a full working demonstration that we could have a play around with? Fiddle?

Comment: i will create one, please wait a minute.

Comment: here it is. quiet simple, both versions, first the problem, second how it should look like. http://jsfiddle.net/8j2Rq/

Comment: @jezzpin, no its not. this simply placed into the lower left window corner by left: 0; bottom: 0. The DIV should grow upwards but the placement should be somewhere in the space, have a look at my example again, scroll around a bit and see the second divs. the gray div is placed with lower left corner to the top of red div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand what you are trying to achieve you want the bottom of the 'drop_up' divs to always be attached to the top of their parent 'flag' divs, i.e. no matter how much content is in either 'flag' or 'drop_up'.

Assuming my understanding is correct I would suggest wrapping the 'drop_up' divs inside another div (which I will call 'drop_upHolder') and then absolute position this new div to the top of the 'flag' div and then absolute position the bottom of the 'drop_up' div this holder div.

e.g.

```
<div class="flag">     
    <div id="drop_upHolder">
        <div id="drop_up">
            ....
            ....
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

.flag #drop_upHolder {
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
  top:0;
  height:0
}
.flag #drop_up {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: gray;
  padding: 25px;
  bottom:0;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: amazing... I will test it out later on but at first sight it looks like it will do the job as i liked to. thanks for so far.